# Notepad++ regex replace $1 only using first digit

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am searching for all dollar amount instances with regex `\$([0-9])+(\.[0-9]{1,2})` and it is working to find all instances of any dollar amount such as:

```
$128.99
$140
$6.82
$4.5
```

However, I am trying to replace the values with the complete values by using `\$1$2` and it is only returning par of the number before the decimal, example using above:

```
$1.99
$1
```

Where it should be showing the full amounts (`$128.99 & $140` in the examples).  Trying to figure where I am going wrong.  I want to replace with **"TEXT"+ Number**.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct regex should be `\$([0-9]+)(\.[0-9]{1,2})?` Or `\$(\d+)(\.\d{1,2})?`

Used `\d` shorthand for `[0-9]`

Replace with `$\1\2`

<kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jA9rH9/1)**</kbd>

Comment: This seems to work!  Great, it is finding all instances I believe and is replacing correctly.

Comment: @Chris: There is always something left or incompatible. Am glad it worked for you.